# Odoo V11 - How can I force computed field as edited manually ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I have a computed field in 'hr.payslip' model.

```
cumulative_income_tax_base_previous = fields.Float(string="Kümülatif 
   Gelir Vergisi Matrahı" 
   compute='_get_previous_payslip_fields',store=True)
```

I want to edit this field according to another field (type is boolean) in same model.

```
first_access = fields.Boolean(string="İlk bordro girişi mi ?", 
default=False)
```

If this field is set to true, I want to edit manually computed field.
In form view, I set readonly:True attribute to my compute field.

```
<xpath expr="//group[@name='accounting']" position="after">
   <group name="other_calculation" string="Dİğer Hesaplamalar">
       <field name="first_access"/>
       <field name="cumulative_income_tax_base_previous"
            attrs="{'readonly':[('first_access', '!=', True)], 
                    'required': [('first_access', '=', True)]}"/>

   </group>
 </xpath>
```

But , I didn't make in python class. When I edit it manually, it is assigned to zero. How can I solve this problem

```
@api.one
@api.depends('employee_id', 'date_from', 'date_to', 'first_access')
def _get_previous_payslip_fields(self):            
 for record in self:
    if record.employee_id and record.date_from and record.date_to 
          and not record.line_ids:

        .... (some codes)

        payslip_object = self.env['hr.payslip'].search(domain, 

        order='id desc', limit=1)


        if payslip_object and not record.first_access:  

          record.gv_rate_init_previous=payslip_object['gv_rate_init']

          record.cumulative_income_tax_base_previous = 
                   payslip_object['cumulative_income_tax_base']
        else:
             ... ? ( When the first access field is set True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `inverse` parameter in your Python field declaration like :

```
cumulative_income_tax_base_previous = fields.Float(string="Kümülatif 
Gelir Vergisi Matrahı" 
compute='_get_previous_payslip_fields',
inveres='_set_previous_payslip_fields',
store=True)
```

See documentation : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields

Comment: Hello, I used inverse parameter and I created _set_previous_payslip_fields() method. After I just only wrote "pass" in this method body. But, result didn't changed. Therefore, I created a field that name "cumulative_income_tax_base_previous_manual" and I did calculations by this fields.

Comment: The `_inverse` method could be used to store data in the database (with a `cr.execute(SQL_REQUEST)` or by setting the value in another field.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in xml force_save="1", and store = True  in Python:
for example:

1. XML:

   ```
   <field name="your_field"  force_save="1"/>
   ```
2. Python:

   ```
   your_fields = fields.Float("Your field", compute=compute_method, store=True)
   ```

Comment: I wrote <field name="gv_rate_init_previous" force_save="1" /> and I added attrs="{'readonly':[('first_access', '!=', True)]. But, there was no change. My python field is :  gv_rate_init_previous = fields.Float(string="GV1 (Önceki)",
                                         digits=dp.get_precision('Payroll Rate'), compute='_get_previous_payslip_fields', store=True). May be, it's from the version number

Comment: No, your code in function cumulative_income_tax_base_previous may be not working, try to print "payslip_object['cumulative_income_tax_base']" and verfiy that diferent to 0 and "payslip_object and not record.first_access" is True